# Acessando componentes de outro Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho dois `Forms` na minha aplicação. Um `Form` para dados de um motor que tem os seguintes campos: `txtPotencia`, `txtTensao` e `txtCorrente`.
Gostaria de acessar os valores preenchidos nesses `TextBox` através de outro `Form`.
No segundo `Form` instanciei um objeto do primeiro Form (MotorForm), porém não tenho acesso aos `TextBox`.

```
public MacroForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MotorForm motorForm = new MotorForm();
    motorForm.Show();
}
```

Tem alguma maneira ?

Comment: Só para eu entender, dentro de `MotorForm` tem os 3 `TextBox`, e você precisa recuperar pelo `MacroForm()`? primeiro você abre o `MacroForm` e logo após abre o `MotoForm()`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. É só criar estes membros com visibilidade pública e acessar pelo outro form.

É possível alterar a visibilidade dos controles do form na caixa *properties* (a mesma onde se altera o nome, texto, etc. dos componentes) e alterando o **modifiers** para public

[image: Alterando a visibilidade pela caixa properties]

Também é possível alterando o arquivo .Designer do form, porém isso não é uma boa ideia uma vez que este código é escrito pelo Visual Studio, então pode acabar sendo reescrito caso seja feita alguma modificação visual nestes componentes.

```
public MacroForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var motorForm = new MotorForm();
    var potencia = motorForm.txtPotencia.Text; 
    //Desde que txtPotencia seja public, isso é válido
}
```

Se você não quiser expor diretamente os controles do *form* como *TextBoxes*, etc. É possível criar métodos públicos (ou *getters* e *setters*) para alterar estes valores

Entretanto, tenha em mente que quanto mais componentes forem "compartilhados" mais código vai precisar ser escrito nesse caso. Muito possível que todo este código seja inútil se a real necessidade é apenas recuperar/*settar* valores para os controles.

Comment: Como altero a visibilidade dos textbox ?

Comment: @RaphaelPradodeOliveira Coloquei um exemplo

Answer (score 3):

Dentro do `MotorForm` crie ***3 métodos*** que vão auxiliar na recuperação, já visto que o `TextBox` a visibilidade é `private` e particularmente não gosto de alterar isso.

```
public class MotorForm: Form
{
    public string Potencia 
    {
        get { return txtPotencia.Text; }
    }
    public string Tensao
    {
        get { return txtTensao.Text; }
    }
    public string Corrente
    {
        get { return txtCorrente.Text; }
    }
}
```

com esses 3 método terá o valores das 3 `TextBox`.

```
public MacroForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MotorForm motorForm = new MotorForm();
    motorForm.Show();

    // já consegue recuperar os valores dos TextBox
    motorForm.Potencia; 
    motorForm.Tensao;
    motorForm.Corrente;
}
```